# Is the "somebody else answered while you were typing" notification working?

Tags: bug, status-norepro, answers

Yesterday I found that I'd answered a question a minute or two after somebody else (with overlap) and thought I had just not seen the notice that you usually get when someone answers while you are.  So I've been paying more attention, and I just noticed another question where I didn't see somebody else's earlier answer (or a notice) before committing mine.  I haven't changed any browser settings and am not blocking any relevant Javascript.  is this happening to anybody else?

Comment: It happened to me just yesterday, but it seems to work most of the time.

Comment: indeed I can repro this on Stack Overflow.. looking

Comment: ah ok never mind, there is an edge condition if you happen to be "composing" 3 answers at once, but it's not relevant.

Comment: I was only composing one answer at a time. :-)

Comment: In few cases, I noticed that I didn't get any notification, but I didn't pay attention for when it happened.

Answer (score 1):

We tried on Stack Overflow and we can't repro this -- we get the answer notification as expected.

Remember pings to the server are every 45 seconds, though.